# android sdk wait for animation to complete

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple game and I need the game to pause until a falling animation is completed and then call the AI move function.

```
Animation animationFalling = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.falling);
iv.startAnimation(animationFalling)
```

then I call the AI's function which does the same command to a different imageview. The problem is that both the images, the players and the AI's are going at the same time. How can I make a small delay to let the first animation finish then start the second?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) to do this.